# toggleClass - два триггера одного класса

Tags: jquery

Как правильно реализовать отображение модального окна по клику на один элемент и скрытие по клику на другой при помощи `toggleClass`?

Мой код ниже работает только наполовину, т.е. работает добавление класса `.md-show`, но не работает удаление по `.md-close`. Возможно ли, что сказывается расположение кнопок в DOM?

P.S.:`.md-close` находится внутри блока, у которого надо удалить класс.

```
$(".md-close, .md-trigger").click(function(){
   $(".modal").toggleClass("md-show");
});
```

Comment: покажите Ваш html, обычное расположение кнопок роли не играет, [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/t99qudxL/1/)

Comment: код выглядит рабочим. Стоит только обратить внимание,  что `$(".modal")` выбирает **все** элементы с классом modal На странице

Comment: он один на странице. Главное - Идентичный код для другого элемента работает отлично!